# SQL Server 2008, searching for special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to locate some bad data that has been inserted into a table.  Likely by someone doing a copy/paste from Word then inserting into the database.

I have seen the similar questions like 
[Query for finding rows with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968042/sql-query-for-finding-rows-with-special-characters-only)

but this doesn't quite work for what I'm needing.  Essentially I want to only return back a data set not including any standard characters and catch things such as an endash (just one example).

I have tried using something like this

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z \-@\.]%'
```

but it returns back every single single record.

---

### EDIT

In case it is of benefit for anyone else that comes along later.  Ultimately the issue I was having was due to the placement of the hyphen (-) character as was also noted by sgmoore below.  I moved this to the beginning of my range just following the not (^) character.

Also, based on the info provided by gbn that LIKE is not actually using regexes I revisited the Microsoft documentation here [SQL Server LIKE Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).  I was using the backslash character unnecessarily as an escape character due to my assumption it was the same as a regex.  These were unnecessary, and apparently escape characters are only needed with wildcard characters.  The doc I linked also mentions using an ESCAPE clause following the LIKE range to specify what character is to be used as an escape character e.g. WHERE percent_complete LIKE '%50!%' ESCAPE '!' would match a string that actually ends in 50% (50%, 150%).

Here is what I ended up using to screen my email data for bad characters; for me it works, but it may not be complete for all cases.

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email LIKE '%[^-0-9a-zA-Z_@.]%'

also if it is helpful, I needed to do something similar on a couple of other generic text fields; this far from comprehensive, but it narrowed my result set down to just a handful of records that I was then able to visually determine what I was looking for.

SELECT * from mytable WHERE text_field LIKE '%[^-0-9a-zA-Z @.''?:/,+&();_]%'

Comment: +1 seems ok to me this question - not sure why it is marked -1

Comment: @whytheq, Thanks I'm not quite sure why I'm getting so many down votes on this question.  Apparently none of the down voters cares to comment as to why either :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z @\.\-]%'
```

It would look like the position of the - sign on your version is causing problems.

Comment: Just saw your post.  Indeed the positioning of the hyphen was an issue.  I moved it to the front of my range.  I also removed the backslashes as they were apparently unnecessary as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use double negatives

```
... WHERE email NOT LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z ,-@\.]%'
```

Sample data would be useful too

Comment: That is not the issue the ^ character at the beginning of my regex match set means NOT contained in the following.  When I run for example ... WHERE name LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z ]%' I get an empty result set as I would expect.  Here I am also trying to screen out hypens, periods, and the @ character, so something in my syntax is not quite right.

Comment: @bigtunacan: did you try it? Also, LIKE is not regex. You only need to escape opening brackets http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661125/sql-server-like-containing-bracket-characters/3661145#3661145

Comment: Sorry, you are correct that it is not regex, but acts similarly to a limited subset of a regex range.  The ^ character at the beginning of the range indicates match only that which is NOT contained in the range as seen here in the official Microsoft docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: @bigtunacan: did you try it?

Comment: Sorry; yes I tried dropping out the ^ and using NOT, the results were the same.  I noticed on the Microsoft documentation an example where they are using the hyphen in the range and it is at the beginning.  So I tried changing my range from '%[^0-9a-zA-Z -@.]%' to '%[^-0-9a-zA-Z @.]%'.  This gave me the results I was expecting.  Maybe this is documented somewhere that the hyphen must be at the beginning; if so I missed, but anyway it works.

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out that it not actually a regex; I was originally also trying to escape characters using \ like I would with a regex such as the hyphen and period, but these are apparently not special characters in the SQL range.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, every email has a `@` character as well as `.`.  You might try:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z ,\]%'
```

If your original list is what you really want, then you need to escape `-`:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z ,\-@\.]%'
```

Comment: Sorry; forgot to escape the hyphen when typing it in the original question.  Even with the hyphen character escaped it is still returning all results.  I have also dropped the comma as was unnecessary for the email field. I've updated my question above; issue is still the same.