# Find documents with fields containing special characters in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

In SQL there exists the syntax:

```
SELECT
    TemplateID,
    Body
FROM
    #Template
WHERE
    Body LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z ]%'
```

Taken from the SQL question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968042/sql-query-for-finding-rows-with-special-characters-only)
Where the expression finds rows with `Body` containing invalid characters (not number or alphabet).

Is there a similarly succinct way to find fields which contain invalid (or special) characters in a MongoDB query?

Answer (score 1):

You can try MongoDB $regsx as below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { 
            $or: [
                {'fieldName': { $regex: "$", $options: 'i' } },
                {'fieldName': { $regex: "#", $options: 'i' } },
                /* Append you special char here in array */
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the regex can be used in Mongo as well as such:

```
db.myCollection.
find(
  {
    "title": {
                 "$regex": ".*[^0-9a-zA-z |,'-:&%].*"
             }
  })
```

Or a cleaner and more elegant regex, based on [(grep) Regex to match non-ASCII characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124010/grep-regex-to-match-non-ascii-characters)

```
db.myCollection.find(
{
    'title': {'$regex': ".*[^[:ascii:]].*"}
},
{
    'title': 1,
    '_id': 0
}
).limit(10)
```