# SQL query finding all strings that contain a character other than what is specified

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need a query that finds rows with a column string value that contains any character other than alphanumeric + specific character.

For example:

```
colName
_______
abc123"
acb231!
bca412++
.4!21
abc
123
```

I want to select all rows that contain **any** characters **other** than

- digits `0-9`
- letters `a-z` (lower or upper case),
- space
- backtick
- Any of the following additional characters `!$%[_-()`

Resulting in:

```
abc123"
.4!21
```

Comment: What have you tried so far

Comment: WHERE colName NOT LIKE '%[^0-9A-Z!+]%'
Lots variants of it too. I'm fairly new to using regex, so I've been playing around with it for a while.

Comment: `NOT LIKE` should be `LIKE` as you are looking for rows that match the pattern https://dbfiddle.uk/LonR70YZ

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query for finding rows with special characters only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968042/sql-query-for-finding-rows-with-special-characters-only)

Comment: Hm, I think the actual issue is that characters I'm inversely selecting for need to be escaped maybe? I also want to include the characters !$%`-_ to be okay. So, a string containing * would still be selected (e.g., *123!)

Comment: No they don't need to be escaped - the main issue is that you are using `NOT LIKE` and should be using `LIKE`. A second issue is that `-` is one of the additional characters and so make sure this is the end character of the set so it isn't interpreted as meaning a range

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified: yes, I tried it with LIKE instead and that worked for the alphanumeric characters. Can you clarify on what you mean by making sure "-" is the end character of the set? As in place it literally at the end of the expression?

Comment: Yes. If it is surrounded by other characters SQL Server interprets that as you having a mixed set of specific characters and a range of characters

Comment: I see, thank you! If I included square brackets as whitelisted characters as well, would I have to escape them then?
Looking like this so far: 

LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-z \[!$%`_()-]%' ESCAPE '\'

Comment: Not sure. Easiest thing to do is first get the positive version of your expression working. Like this https://dbfiddle.uk/EXuqNSXd and then when that is returning exactly the characters you need then add the `^` onto it to get the negated version

Comment: you had the casing wrong in your previous comment (`A-z` needs to be `A-Z`) https://dbfiddle.uk/SE9gg9ET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the full requirement described in the comments this was trickier than I thought it would be

but

```
LIKE '%[^- !$%`_()\]0-9a-zA-Z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 ESCAPE '\'
```

does the job.

The `]` is escaped with `\` and the `-` is put at the beginning of the set so it is not interpreted as being in the role of a range (as later in the pattern)

To validate this is correct I find it simplest to check the positive version against all characters first ([DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JMlrgxhK)).

```
SELECT CharCode = value, 
       Character = NCHAR(value)
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0,65535)
WHERE NCHAR(value) LIKE '%[- !$%`_()\]0-9a-zA-Z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 ESCAPE '\'
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use the [like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) operator to match the pattern you are looking for.

The [pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#pattern) is `[^a-z0-9!+]`

Here is the [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/62085/4):

```
select
   colName 
from
   input_table
where
   colName like '%[^a-z0-9!+]%'
```

| colName |
| --- |
| abc123" |
| .4!21 |